# Can't use MySqlConnection methods outside function

Tags: c#, mysql, class, database-connection

I am new coding and I am trying to create a model `DBContext`.

I instantiated a connection `conn` using `MySqlConnection`. Then I perceived it didn't me allow to use `conn` methods (like `conn.Open()`).

I have found a code that uses it inside a function and it seems to work. However I couldn't understand why it has to be inside a function.

Here is my code:

```
public class DBContext
{
    //Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
    //start creating connection string
    public static string ConnectString
    {
        get { return "Server=localhost;Database=blog;Uid=root;Pwd=root;"; }

    }
    public string ConnectionTest()
    {
        //create an instance of connection
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();//Here I can use conn properties/methods

        return "";
    }

    //create an instance of connection
    MySqlConnection conn2 = new MySqlConnection();//Here I can't
    conn2.open();
}
```

After reading some documentation about classes and method I understand that classes are references therefore it will not "run".

However I couldn't understand why the error when using `conn2.open()` is

> conn2.open() does not exist in the current context.

shouldn't conn2 exist in the "class context"?

Comment: Are you getting any compile-time or run-time error? If yes, can you include in the question the details of this error?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias error added

Comment: Don't you want to put the `conn2.open();` code inside some method of the `DBContext` class? Otherwise, when this code is it supposed to run?

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/classes and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/methods

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I was thinking about creating the connection when the class was instantiated, but after reading documentation provided above, I saw that what I needed actually was a constructor.
However, even though I understood that classes are references and not actually a running code, I still don't get the error message. Shouldn't conn2 exists in the "class context"?

Comment: Never cache connection objects if you can help it. Create them when you need them, and dispose with `using` in the same function. Under certain circumstances you can cache, but you *must* make sure to dispose properly with `IDisposable`

Comment: @EwertonXavier no, this is not how it works. I think that you need to study the [general structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/) of a C# program. There might be better tutorials available than this out there.